# How can I remove Ruby on Rails 4 beta?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and I installed the latest beta version of Rails 4 on my Mac, before I installed RVM to manage my versions. The Rails 4 beta is becoming a huge pain in the ass because it's the default version in every new tab I open in the terminal. How can I uninstall the Rails 4 beta and all references to it?

Answer (score 19):

Except of uninstalling rails you need to uninstall railties gem - rails exec is only wrapper that will select most up-to-date railties gem.

```
$ gem uninstall rails -v=4.0.0.beta1
$ gem uninstall railties -v=4.0.0.beta1
```

Comment: rails -v still showed "rails 4.0.0" and after doing uninstall on railties it solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ gem uninstall rails -v=4.0.0.beta1
```

or

```
$ gem uninstall rails
```

and you will be asked which version to uninstall (if there are more than one).

Comment: I did this for the rc, and it doenst show up when I do gem list, but Rails is still set 4.0.0.rc1 when I do rails -v.  Wondering if this is an rvm issue? Very bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as ckarbass (Rails was still set at 4.0.0.rc1 when I entered `rails -v`). To solve it, I used Bernard Potocki's advice, but took into consideration that I had a different version.

To make it possible for whatever version you may have, just do:

`gem uninstall rails`

Then, select the version of Rails 4 you have and delete it.

Then, do:

`gem uninstall railties`

And do the same thing.

When I uninstalled the Rails 4 version of railties, it told me that dependencies for a couple gems (coffee-rails and sass-rails) wouldn't be met. So I just did the same thing with both of them as I did above, and deleted their Rails 4 versions as well (for example, for sass-rails, I had a version installed called sass-rails-4.0.0.rc1).

And done! The terminal now lists 3.2.13 as my current Rails version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Rails 4.0.0 final version.  I used all what was mentioned before with no success.  What helped was listing all my gems, I'm using Windows, so it was:

```
>pik gem list
```

Then I checked the rails versions.  It showed rails 3.2.14 (what I wanted) with railties 4.0.0, 4.0.0.rc2 and 3.2.14.

I then ran

```
gem uninstall railties
```

and uninstalled all other versions except 3.2.14 and now it works well.  The problem was that when Rails 3.2 installation is called, the latest (or all) versions of railties is installed.

Answer (score -1):

Do

```
$ gem uninstall rails
```

and choose the version 4 beta as the one to uninstall. Do not worry about unmatched dependencies at this point. Just say 'yes' to go ahead with the uninstall.

Once it is gone, do

```
$ gem install rails
```

This will get and install the latest released version for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker wants to downgrade their Rails version, not upgrade it.

Comment: It would have worked when it was written, as rails 4 was not released then. :)

Comment: So how should we write it now?