# How to switch between rails3.2 to rails4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed rails3.2.13 and rails4.0 on my pc.Browsercms needs rails3.2 and don't support  rails4.0,so when I run browsercms, I need to swicth from rails4.0(general use) to rails3.2.The way is:

```
$rvm use 1.9.3
$gem install rails -v 3.2.13
$rvm gemset create rails3.2
$rvm use 1.9.3@rails3.2
$rvm info
```

It can switch from rails4.0 to rails3.2.but after I want to be back to rails4.0,but can't complete.So how can I switch from rails3.2 to rails4.0?

Comment: See the following SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271338/downgrading-rails-4-to-3-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'` in your app's Gemfile.